# Exec php tar command to backup website dynamically

Tags: php, linux, exec, backup, tar

I'd like to make a backup of my website using `tar` command and `exec` in `Php` and I wrote a small script to does that but nothing happens... where I fault? I have php 5.6.5 and hosting linux that has `exec` enabled and `tar` command available. Here is a `Php` example what I'd like to do.

```
<?php
  $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  # root is /web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/
  $name = "backup_" . date("[d-m-Y][H-i]") . ".tar.gz";
  # name is backup_[25-02-2015][18-57].tar.gz
  $skip = "*.gz";
  # skip is the file I want to exclude (example: skip backup_[25-02-2015][18-57].tar.gz)
  if ((substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],-1,1) == "/") && (substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,1) =="/")) {
    $sdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),1);
  } else {
    $sdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }
  # sdir is /web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/bak/ and is the path where the script lives
  # out is the output
  # oky is the success o failed exec command
  function backup()  {
    exec("tar -cvf $sdir/$name $root/* --exclude='$sdir/$skip' ", $out, $oky);
  }
  backup();
  if (!$oky) {
    echo "$out: Backup Completed!";
  } else {
    echo "$out: Backup Not Completed!";
  }
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: None of the variables in the string in the function `backup()` are available inside the function, and the other two are not available outside the function: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$oky` and `$out` are local variables. They are not set outside the function. `$sdir`, `$name` and `$root` are not defined within the function.

**Method 1 - Parameters:**

```
function backup($sdir,$name,$root,$salt)  {
    exec("tar -cvf $sdir/$name $root/* --exclude='$sdir/$salt' ", $out, $oky);
    return array("oky"=>$oky, "out"=>$out);
}

$result = backup($sdir, $name, $root, $salt);

if (!$result["oky"]) {
    echo $result["out"].": Backup Completed!";
} else {
    echo $result["out"].": Backup Not Completed!";
}
```

**Method 2 - Don't use a function:**

```
exec("tar -cvf $sdir/$name $root/* --exclude='$sdir/$salt' ", $out, $oky);

if (!$oky) {
    echo "$out: Backup Completed!";
} else {
    echo "$out: Backup Not Completed!";
}
```

**Method 3 - Global variables:**

```
function backup()  {
    global $sdir,$name,$root,$salt,$oky,$out;
    exec("tar -cvf $sdir/$name $root/* --exclude='$sdir/$salt' ", $out, $oky);
}

backup();

if (!$oky) {
    echo "$out: Backup Completed!";
} else {
    echo "$out: Backup Not Completed!";
}
```